# Protocol Buffers repeated field

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I got this in my `.proto` file:

```
message Request {
    repeated string test = 2;
//    string test = 2;

}
```

There is a function:

```
def hash_md5(data):
    print(data)
    return data
```

There is a `client` code:

```
channel = grpc.insecure_channel('localhost:6066')
stub = mle_service_pb2_grpc.DataHashStub(channel)
text = ['Scio me nihil scire']
to_md5 = mle_service_pb2.Request(test=text)
response = stub.hash_md5(to_md5)
print('-----------',response)
```

But there is an exception `Exception calling application: Assignment not allowed to repeated field "test" in protocol message object`. If I change type in `.proto` forexample to string and change in `client` `to text = ['Scio me nihil scire']` all works. How can I fix it with repeated type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's confusing (and bit me too) but you can't assign repeated fields (or messages) directly.

See [Repeated Fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#repeated-fields)